# How to limit whois servers and TLDs in Domain Search of WHMCS

Tags: whmcs

I've seen options to control this, but now that I need them I can't find them.

When a domain name is searched for in my WHMCS install there are as many as 100 TLDs that are searched and status listed (Available/Unavailable). I have a lot of TLDs configured in the Pricing setup of WHMCS, but these were intended to be made available in a dropdown listbox - not to be searched all inclusively each time a domain name is searched for. It's a bad user experience.

How do I limit which TLDs are searched by default on the WHMCS frontend Domain Search pages?

Answer (score 0):

In WHMCS there are two pages where you can search for available domains which in my opinion is very confusing.

Please see both here:

1) http://demo.whmcs.com/domainchecker.php

2) http://demo.whmcs.com/cart.php?a=add&domain=register

You probably need second one.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage them at: Setup > Products/Services > Domain Pricing

For How-To, [check the documentation](https://docs.whmcs.com/Domain_Pricing).